# org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Concatenation href

Tags: java, spring, web, thymeleaf

I want to concat `cloudfront.net/css/sample.css`.

I get the following error:

> Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Could not parse as expression: "${cloudfrontBaseURL} + css/sample.css".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concat like this:

```
<div th:text="${cloudfrontBaseURL} + 'css/sample.css'"></div>
```

or

```
<div th:text="|${cloudfrontBaseURL}css/sample.css|"></div>
```

https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#literal-substitutions